# Finding a string and retrieving the text next to it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the retrieved the following source code:

```
class="show_small">Date: 2018-05-15 11:30:30<br/></span><span 
class="show_small ">Value: XXX<br/><span class="transfer-usd" 
title="now">YYY<span</span>Tx: <a class="local-link" href="/tx/IJK">IJK</a> 
<br/>From: <a class="local-link" href="/address/ABCD">ABCD</a><br/>To: <a 
class="local-link" href="/address/EFGH">EFGH</a></div>
```

And I would like to retrieve the following info from it: 
Date: 2018-05-15 11:30:30
Value: XXX
transfer USD: YYY
From: ABCD
To: EFGH

I have tried extracting the pieces of info with Pythons beautiful soup, which does work for some variables, but not for all:

```
transactions = page_soup.findAll("span", {"title": "now"})
for transaction in transactions:
    value = transaction.find('span').previous_sibling
    print(value)
```

Now the question is whether there is a way (likely with regular expressions) to search for the words (i.e. "Date:", "To:", ...) and retrieve the text next to it (until the next "<") instead of trying to search using classes in the source code (i.e. span, class, etc.)? I have tried with str.split, str.match, etc., but nothing seems to work.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this just for one record, or are you going to be iterating through a list within a page? The problem with your first BeautifulSoup (BS) code is that only some of the data is contained within `span` tags. I think you need to write a discreen piece of extraction logic for each field (perhaps as a separate method / function) and then apply each one to the code.

Comment: Hi Phil, yes, exactly, I am looping through hundreds of these blocks to retrieve the values for each variable (all have the same logic as shown above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample to show how you could use the different arguments available within BeautifulSoup to navigate each transaction depending on class, contents or other tag properties. Take a look at [the BS docs for find_all / findAll](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all), (depending on version) to find out more.

```
import bs4 

code_sample = '<div name="record"><span class="show_small">Date: 2018-05-15 11:30:30<br/></span><span class="show_small ">Value: 123<br/></span><span class="transfer-usd" title="now">YYY</span>Tx: <a class="local-link" href="/tx/IJK">IJK</a><br/>From: <a class="local-link" href="/address/ABCD">ABCD</a><br/>To: <a class="local-link" href="/address/EFGH">EFGH</a></div>'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(code_sample)
transactions = soup.find_all('div')

for transaction in transactions:
    output = {}
    output["date"] = transaction.find_all(string=re.compile('Date'))
    output["value"] = transaction.find_all(string=re.compile('Value'))
    output["transfer USD"] = transaction.find('span', class_="transfer-usd").contents
    print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'date': ['Date: 2018-05-15 11:30:30'], 'value': ['Value: 123'], 'transfer USD': ['YYY']}
```

You can then manipulate and format the strings however you prefer.

Comment: @carolin Did this help at all? If so and it answered your query could you mark it as solved?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I had to do some data cleaning before returning to this piece. Yes, works as expected! Many thanks for your help!